# Как исправить ошибку InvalidKeyOrUnauthorizedURLMapError?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api, google-maps

При попытке использовать форму с автозаполнением [отсюда](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform) на своем локальном сайте вылетает ошибка `InvalidKeyOrUnauthorizedURLMapError`.

Как это исправить? Весь код на сайте полностью скопирован из примера с целью проверки, чтобы впоследствии переделать под свои нужды.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно подключить Maps API в личном кабинете Google Developers, получить ключ доступа к API и использовать его в коде, вставив в этой строке:

```
 <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&signed_in=true&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete"
```

вместо API_KEY.